# How to unmount an ecryptfs .Private directory mounted at /tmp?

Tags: mount, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs, tmp

Say that I want to view the contents of an encrypted home directory, I can simply use "sudo ecryptfs-recover-private " and it will mount an unencrypted copy at /tmp. That's all fine and good, but how do I unmount it from /tmp? The /tmp directory gets cleared at every startup I believe, but what if I want to remove the /tmp ecryptfs directory without rebooting? I can't just delete the folder because it's read-only.

Is there some way to unmount the directory, or is restarting the only option?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you had remounted the directory as read-write, you still wouldn't want to delete the directory, or you would be erasing the files in your home directory.

I believe what you're looking for is the either the [`ecryptfs-umount-private`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ecryptfs-umount-private.1.html) or [`unmount.ecryptfs_private`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/umount.ecryptfs_private.1.html) command. Be sure to read the warning in the synopsis for that second command.

Comment: This is answer not really helpful, as it does not give any further informations on *how* to remove the direcoty mounted in `/tmp`. That @Mixx shouldn't delete  `/tmp`, as it removes the files on the disk too, is not true. `sudo ecyptfs-recover-private` mounts the disk in readonly mode by default (at least on my system).

Comment: Removal is not the nature of the question. The nature of the question how to unmount.

Comment: You are right, my comment was misleading. I can't edit it anymore, but what I should have written is: "This is answer not really helpful, as it does not give any further informations on _how_ to *unmount* the directory, mounted in `/tmp` "

Comment: To specify my request further I created this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1138613/461976