# Finding ecrypt-recover-private mountpoint

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs, umount

After heavily struggling on mounting my ecrypted hdd, I now want to securely unmount the recovered hdd. I did it as proposed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/624152).

It was mounted by using

```
$user> cd /media/$user/exthdd/home/.ecryptfs/$user/
$user> sudo ecryptfs-recover-private .Private
```

The drive was then mounted under `/tmp/$hash/` in readonly mode.
Now I want to unmount the drive but

```
$user> sudo ecryptfs-umount-private ./Private
fopen: No such file or directory
Cannot chdir into mountpoint.
```

How does it work? I can't find any helpful informations on that in the manual nor online.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `sudo umount.ecryptfs /tmp/ecryptfs.xyz` and it works.

You might have the following message :
`Could not unlink the key(s) from your keying. Please use 'keyctl unlink' if you wish to remove the key(s). Proceeding with umount.`

You can do `sudo keyctl clear @u` to clear the keys.